# ILE RPG Bind by reference using CRTSQLRPGI

Tags: service, rpgle

I've been trying a solution for this, but. I cannot find it.

What I'm trying to do, is work with the "bind by reference" ability, but working with ILE RPG written with embedded sql.

I can use the BNDDIR ctl opt in my source. And everything works correctly.
But that means a "bind by copy" method. Checked deleting the SRVPGM and even the BINDDIR. And the caller program still works.

So, is there any way to use "bind by reference" in an ILERPGSQL program?

After my question, an example:

Program SNILOG is a module, that conains several procedures. Part of them, exported.
In QSRVSRC I set the exported procedures, with a source with the same name: SNILOG. Something like this:

```
STRPGMEXP PGMLVL(*CURRENT)
/************************************************** ******************/
/* *MODULE SNILOG INIGREDI 04/10/21 15:25:30 */
/************************************************** ******************/
EXPORT SYMBOL("GETDIAG_TOSTRING")
EXPORT SYMBOL("GETDIAGNOSTICS")
EXPORT SYMBOL("GRABAR_LOG")
EXPORT SYMBOL("SNILOG")
ENDPGMEXP
```

As part of the procedures are programmed with embedded sql, the compilation must be done with CRTSQLRPGI, using the parameter OBJTYPE(*SRVPGM).
So, I finally get a SRVPGM called SNILOG, with those 4 procedures exported.

Once I've got the SRVPGM, I add it to a BNDDIR called SNI_BNDDIR.

Ok, let's go to the caller program: SNI600V.
Defined with

> dftactgrp(*no)

, of course!.
And compiled with CRTSQLRPGI and parameter OBJTYPE(*PGM).

Here, if I use the control spec

> bnddir('SNI_BNDDIR')

, it works fine.
But not fine enough, as this is a "bind by copy" method (I can delete the SRVPGM or the BNDDIR, and it is still working fine).

When I'm not working with SQL, I can use the CRTPGM command, and I can set the BNDSRVPGM parameter, to set the SRVPGM the program is going to be called. Well, just their procedures...
But I cannot find any similar option in CRTSQLRPGI command.
Nor in opt codes in ctl-opt sentence (We have BNDDIR, but not BNDSRVPGM option).

Any idea?

I'm running V7R3M0 with TR level: 6

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the ACTGRP where the SRVPGM is is active when you delete the object, then the program still works because the activated version is still available. if you reclaim the ACTGRP then the caller complaints it cannot find your SRVPGM. Does it explain your problem ?

Comment: Yes!, you're right.
That was my (first) fault.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the use of
`bnddir('SNI_BNDDIR')`

Is the way to bind by reference OR bind by copy.

The key is what does your BNDDIR look like?

***If you want to bind by reference***, then it should include *SRVPGM objects.

***If you want to bind by copy***, then it should include *MODULE objects.

Generally, you want a *BNDDIR for every *SRVPGM that includes the modules (and maybe a utility *SRVPGM or two) needed for building a specific *SRVPGM.

Then one or more *BNDDIR that includes just *SRVPGM objects that are used to build the programs that use those *SRVPGMs.

Comment: Yes!!

Thanks!
That was my error.
As you have said, the key is which kind of object have you bound into de BNDDIR.

The problem I got is when you try to create the SRVPGM using CRTSQLRPGI.
If you create the SRVPGM using that, you need (in advance) the source of the binding language in QSRVSRC, to set the exports.
But if yoou create a module, and then a SRVPGM using CRTSRVPGM, you can set the parameter EXPORT to *ALL and then you don't need anything in QSRVSRC (or you can set other file and member).


Now it's clear. Thanks!

Comment: @Íñigo EXPORT(*ALL) is a bad practice.  Best practice is to use binder source in QSRVSRC with a manually specified signature.

Comment: Ok. I will keep that in mind. Thanks!